# python requests: how can I get the "exception code"

Tags: python, exception

I am using "requests (2.5.1)" .now I want to catch the exception and return an dict with some exception message,the dict I will return is as following:

```
{
   "status_code":   61, # exception code,
   "msg": "error msg",
}
```

but now I can't get the error status_code and error message,I try to use

```
try:
.....
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
response={
            u'status_code':4040,
            u'errno': e.errno,
            u'message': (e.message.reason),
            u'strerror': e.strerror,
            u'response':e.response,
        }
```

but it's too redundancy,how can I get the error message simplicity?anyone can give some idea?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're trying to do. What's so redundant about the code you've shared?

Comment: I want to catch different type of exception and get the reason of exception,then return a dict,so if someone call my function,it will display the reason that the request failed.. sorry for my bad english

Comment: You could catch a set of exceptions in a tuple, like `except (ConnectionError, ValueError, IndexError) as e`, then in that block, lookup the type in a dict and return the customized status code based on that?

Comment: "return the customized status code",so requests doesn't have its own exception status code?if this,I know how to do this,it's just like  @NoMorePuppies anwsered....still thank you

Comment: You can do `response.raise_for_status` or something like that, and it'll throw an exception when there's a non 200 response status code.

Comment: can you describe it more clealy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try:
    #the codes that you want to catch errors goes here
except:
    print ("an error occured.")
```

This going to catch all errors, but better you define the errors instead of catching all of them and printing special sentences for errors.Like;

```
try:
    #the codes that you want to catch errors goes here
except SyntaxError:
    print ("SyntaxError occured.")
except ValueError:
    print ("ValueError occured.")
except:
    print ("another error occured.")
```

Or;

```
try:
    #the codes that you want to catch errors goes here 
except Exception as t:
    print ("{} occured.".format(t))
```